# Does cloudflare change my server IP address?

Tags: ip-address, ping, cloudflare

I use cloudflare for DNS management. Does it change my IP address? I've heard that I cannot get my default IP address of my server with `ping`, so how to get my default IP address?

Comment: What is a "default IP address"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CloudFlare doesn't change your server IP address. If you're doing lookups against the domain, however, our IPs are going to show because we act as a reverse proxy for your site (doing a dig, ping, traceroute, etc. to the domain will show our IPs). We're still resolving the site to the IP address you have in your DNS settings.

Comment: so nobody (except the owner) can know our server/domain ip. is this correct??

Comment: Correct. Nobody can because your IP is like hiding behind the proxy.

Comment: Is it the case of Cloudflare DNS only configuration, i.e., using the gray cloud? I mean - Does using CF DNS only for faster domain resolution make the origin IP hide or change? Please suggest.